# import errors in maven project

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, sequencefile

Getting **import can not be resolved errors** in maven project even though all the required dependencies have been added to the pom.xml.
Here are the imports which are getting errored:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.CreateFlag;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.CreateOpts;
```

And these are the dependencies that are there in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
```

Can someone please point out what could possibly be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When do you get these errors? When building with maven or in your IDE? Please provide the full error message.

Comment: No not during maven build but in eclipse IDE. After build I am trying to run it as java application but getting import cannot be resolved  for imports shared in the posted question.

Comment: I've just add dependencies and imports are fine. Did you configure your maven properly? check your settings.xml and try reimport.

Comment: Then the most likely case is that the Eclipse workspace is not in sync with the pom.xml and hence does not know anything of the dependencies declared there.

Comment: Can you just go to Maven -> Update dependencies and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the possible options like removing old .m2 directory, update project, checked settings.xml etc but none of them seemed to help. So I finally installed the eclipse again and it worked! Seems like there was something wrong with the IDE but not sure what exactly was wrong.

Thanks everyone for responding with the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out different solutions:
- Try another version of the Hadoop libraries
- Delete the complete .m2 repository in your user folder and redownload the libraries
- Check if your project is configured as a Maven project in your IDE

Good luck!